# virtual keyboard appears on lock screen app

Tags: android

We have designed a lock screen app but the problem is when in other apps we work with virtual keyboard and then we press power button twice, that virtual keyboard remains active, lock screen appears and that virtual keyboard covers the lock screen.

[image]

```java
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {

    this.getWindow().setType(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     this.getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
    );

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 public void keyBoardHide() {
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```